# Inheritance: Type vs. Value

Tags: c#, inheritance

Quick question regarding inheritance. I have a base class `Baseclass` and two subclasses `Subclass1` and `Subclass2`. I have a `ManualResetEvent Mre` defined in `Baseclass`, which is used for cancellation of methods in the subclasses.

In MainForm I do:

```
private Baseclass _baseclass;

private void Start()
{
   if(XYZ)
   {
       var Subclass1 s1 = new Subclass1();
       _baseclass = s1;
       s1.DoCancelableWork();
    }
    else
    {
       var Subclass2 s2 = new Subclass2();
       _baseclass = s2;
       s2.DoCancelableWork();
    }
}

private void Stop()
{
    if(_baseclass != null) _baseclass.Mre.Set();
}

private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(_baseclass != null)
    {
        if(!_baseclass.Mre.WaitOne(0)) Stop();
    }
}
```

Let's say the `DoCancelableWork()` methods run in perpetuity, until the `Mre` it inherits from `Baseclass` is set (I do not define that `Mre` again in the subclasses). When `Stop()` is run, does `_baseclass.Mre` now refer to the `Mre` used in the appropriate subclass, so `DoCancelableWork()` is canceled?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but there's only one instance of `_baseclass`, so whether you treat is as a `BaseClass` or a subclass the value is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. Derived classes have everything the base class does (it effectively has an instance of the base class as "part" of it).

So, if you store a derived class instance in a base class reference, then do something to a base class member *through* that reference, the derived class is *still* pointing at/using it (since they are actually the same object).

To clarify your additional questions:

> `Subclass s = new Subclass()`, and`Baseclass b = new Subclass()`. Is
>   there a clear practical difference?

No. There is no difference at all in terms of functionality. By storing it as a derived type, you get access to the derived-only members and can avoid downcasting later. If you store it off as the base class, you are implying that you will only access it as the base class type later (using polymorphism to get the derived class behavior).

> Let's say I just had `Subclass s1 = new Subclass()`, and I never did
>   the `_baseclass = s1`. Would there be any way to check if the
>   Baseclass has been instantiated (as it has, through the Subclass)?

No. There is no *need* to check such a thing, since the constructor semantic for derived classes *always* also creates the base class. It uses the default constructor when available. If its not available, your derived constructors have to explicitly invoke the desired base class one:

```
public DerivedClass(string someArg) : base(someArg)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. Perhaps this comes down to that I don't really understand the difference between `Subclass s = new Subclass()`,  and `Baseclass b = new Subclass()`. Is there a clear practical difference? Also, let's say I just had `Subclass s1 = new Subclass()`, and I never did the `_baseclass = s1`. Would there be any way to check if the Baseclass has been instantiated (as it has, through the Subclass)? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks, Bradley, super helpful. The reason I asked if there is any way to check if `Baseclass` has been implicitly instantiated, was due to my `Stop()` and `FormClosing()` methods, above. They both want to set the `Mre` that belongs to the particular `DoCancelableWork()` that is now running (it could be the one in s1, or the one in s2). I did not want to have many if-statements in the `Stop()` method, and instead just one check for whether the Baseclass was instantiated (as that has the power to stop any subclass). Is there a better way to do this than setting _baseclass=s1 or s2, etc.?

Comment: @Anders I'm really not sure what you are getting at. A base class instance is *always* created when a derived class one is, so just call `Stop` on `s1`, `s2`, etc. The appropriate instance will be used, since the derived class instance **is also** the base class instance.

Comment: Yeah, but I would then have to define _s1 and _s2 as global variables. Then, in Stop(), i would have to have multiple lines, one for each Subclass instance. Instead, I wanted only one line in Stop() and one global instance, and with that be able to stop the appropriate subclass. You can see this issue taken to the extreme, if I have many subclasses (s1, s2, s3,...,s50).

Comment: @Anders Subclasses don't share base class instances, like I said, they are one and the same. So that will never work. If you want to stop a bunch, then hold them in a list and use `foreach`

Comment: Or do it the way I did it above, and set 'if(x) _basclass = s1; else if(y) _baseclass = s2; else if(z) _baseclass = s3`, etc. Right? It seems to work..

Comment: @Anders Sure, but that wouldn't let you stop 100 different instances at once.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I might not have been clear enough. There is only one subclass instance running at the time. So, I don't need to stop several at once, I only need to stop the one that is currently running (which could be one of 100 different ones if in Start there were 100 instances defined).

Comment: @Anders Then just store off the reference when you start it and stop it later, no condition required :)

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but I really want to get to the bottom of this :) You mean doing it the way I have done it in my first post, right? When I create a specific `Subclass` instance I store it in `_baseclass`. That way I can just do `_baseclass.Set()` in `Stop()`. If I had not stored it in `_baseclass`, there would have been no way for me to know which one of the 100 instances is the live one. Not sure if it makes a difference, but the condition in the if-statement in `Start()`, that decides which `Subclass` gets instantiated, comes from radio-buttons in the UI.

Comment: @Anders Yes, exactly the way you are doing it. I misunderstood where the condition was :)